# Execute dynamic query and assign values into two variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following dynamic query to execute and assign the result into two variables.

```
DECLARE @MinDate VARCHAR(10) = ''
DECLARE @MaxDate VARCHAR(10) = ''

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @MinDate = Convert(Varchar,Cast(Min(ColumnDate) AS DATE),105),
                   @MaxDate = Convert(Varchar,Cast(Max(ColumnDate) AS DATE),105)
            FROM ['+@Table+']';

PRINT(@SQL);
EXEC(@SQL)

PRINT(@MinDate);
PRINT(@MaxDate);
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@MaxDate".

Comment: `EXEC` can't assign variables that aren't in its own, local scope. Use `sp_executesql` and output parameters (e.g. `DECLARE @d DATETIME; EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @d = GETDATE()', N'@d DATETIME OUTPUT', @d = @d OUTPUT; SELECT @d;`).

Comment: What you have there is **very** open to Injection. Consider using `QUOTENAME` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jeroen Mostert correctly said in the comments, you need to use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `EXEC`.

`sp_executesql` allows to provide parameters to the dynamic SQL and these parameters can be marked as `OUTPUT`, which you need here.

Besides, it is good to use proper parameters where you can to prevent SQL injection issues. In your example `@MinDate` and `@MaxDate` can and should be made as proper parameters. `@Table` can't become a parameter, so it will remain concatenated to SQL string. Only this part would remain open to SQL injection.

Here is a example:

```
DECLARE @MinDate_ VARCHAR(10) = '';
DECLARE @MaxDate_ VARCHAR(10) = '';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SET @SQL = 
    'SELECT 
        @MinDate = Convert(Varchar,Cast(Min(ColumnDate) AS DATE),105),
        @MaxDate = Convert(Varchar,Cast(Max(ColumnDate) AS DATE),105)
    FROM ['+@Table+']';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    ,N'@MinDate VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT, @MaxDate VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT'
    ,@MinDate = @MinDate_ OUTPUT
    ,@MaxDate = @MaxDate_ OUTPUT
;

SELECT @MinDate_, @MaxDate_;
```

Note, that you have to specify `OUTPUT` twice.

You can use the same name `@MinDate` for parameter that you declare outside the dynamic SQL and inside dynamic SQL, but I prefer to give them different names (`@MinDate` and `@MinDate_`), so I'm not confused what is what.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place your variables in your string:

```
SET @SQL = '
DECLARE @MinDate VARCHAR(10) = ''''
DECLARE @MaxDate VARCHAR(10) = ''''

SELECT @MinDate = Convert(Varchar,Cast(Min(ColumnDate) AS DATE),105),
       @MaxDate = Convert(Varchar,Cast(Max(ColumnDate) AS DATE),105)
FROM ['+@Table+']

PRINT(@MinDate)
PRINT(@MaxDate)
            '
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: This is still wide open to injection.